# How to open udp in iptables on 9003?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm setting up a new UDP server on my CentOS, and I user `iptables`. But I can't connect my server if I start the `iptable`.

I save the filter chain like this :

[image]

But it doesn't work;

I use `nc -ul 9003` to listen this port ;and I use another `nc send msg`; but I can't get my `msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete Rule Number 7 and it should work. Or Insert the Rules above Rule Number 7.
I would recommend using the Chain Policy to block every traffic that is not allowed.

How to Delete iptable Rules:

```
iptables -D INPUT (Rule Number)
```

How to insert iptable Rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT (Rule Number) (Rule)
```

Answer (score -1):

centos uses firewalld by default

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9003/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

but if you are using iptables then

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp--dport 9003 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```